# Make global variable from another func

Tags: json, go, global-variables

How make global json config and use it everywhere?

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // Use config
    fmt.Println(config["Keywords"]) // <-- USE HERE
}

func main() {
    config := models.Conf() // Init there!
    fmt.Println(config.Keywords) // This prints "keywords1" - good

    // Routes
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)

    // Get port
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/liamka/15eec829d516da4cb511

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply that in main you create a new config instance instead of using the global variable

You have:

```
var config map[string]*models.Config
```

Which is the global var. and in main() you have:

```
func main() {

config := models.Conf()
...
```

which creates a local variable and throws it away. This is what you need to do:

The global var:

```
var config models.Config
```

In main:

```
func main() {

config = models.Conf()
...
```

this will reference the global variable and not the local one.

Comment: if i wrote this:
config = models.Conf()
that types error:
`cannot use models.Conf() (type models.Config) as type map[string]*models.Config in assignment`
and
`config.Keywords undefined (type map[string]*models.Config has no field or method Keywords)`

Comment: @Gopher Of course they need to be the same, make the global variable whatever that function returns.

Comment: Not working.
`Conf := models.Conf()`
`fmt.Println(Conf.Keywords)`
Can you please write right answer?

Comment: @Gopher I've changed my answer, have a look